# SQL Server : aggregate by sequenced number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sequence, gaps-and-islands

I need some help to aggregate some data. Imagine I have the following table:

```
number  Name    From Date   To Date     Sequency No_
----------------------------------------------------
123440  MJCL    03/12/2014  02/09/2015  1
123440  MJCL    07/09/2015  06/03/2016  1
123440  MJCL    07/03/2016  06/09/2016  2
123440  MJCL    07/09/2016  06/03/2017  3
123440  MJCL    07/03/2017  31/12/9999  4
123442  GJSVF   15/12/2014  14/06/2015  1
123442  GJSVF   15/06/2015  14/12/2015  2
123442  GJSVF   15/12/2015  14/06/2016  3
123442  GJSVF   27/03/2017  26/03/2018  1
```

I need a SQL query to output the following:

```
number  Name    From Date   To Date
--------------------------------------
123440  MJCL    03/12/2014  02/09/2015
123440  MJCL    07/09/2015  31/12/9999
123442  GJSVF   15/12/2014  14/06/2016
123442  GJSVF   27/03/2017  26/03/2018
```

Basically what I need is to join the rows by `[Sequency No_]` and return the `[From Date]` of `[Sequency No_] = 1` and the `[To Date]` from last `[Sequency No_]` of the sequence. Any ideas?

Note that the database is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I tryed the gaps and islands problem resolution that a saw in other question but I was missing to add my group in group by statment. The answer of  Pரதீப் solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called as *[gaps and islands](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)* problem.

Here is one trick using `Row_Number` window function

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Grp = Row_number()OVER(partition BY number ORDER BY [From Date],[Sequency No_]) - [Sequency No_]
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT number,
       NAME,
       [From Date] = Min([From Date]),
       [To Date] = Max([To Date])
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY number,
          NAME,
          Grp
```

- [**Demo**](http://rextester.com/LBIMA8496)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..this will work for you :)

```
SELECT number,Name,MAX(From_Date) From_Date,MAX(To_Date) To_Date
FROM   Trans_Tab
GROUP BY number,Name

UNION ALL

SELECT number,Name,MIN(From_Date) From_Date,MIN(To_Date) To_Date
FROM   Trans_Tab
GROUP BY number,Name
ORDER BY number,Name
```

Comment: This gives me the first and last record for each number.  I need to join the rows by [Sequency No_] and return the [From Date] of [Sequency No_] = 1 and the [To Date] from last [Sequency No_] of the sequence. The Pரதீப் answer works to me. Thanks!